# Is there a better way to represent enum with same values?

Tags: python

```
class FuzzyTime(Enum):
    morning = 1
    dawn = 2
    noon = 3
    midday = 4
    afternoon = 5
    evening = 6
    sunset = 7
    dusk = 8
    night = 9
```

In those cases, I want to represent morning & dawn, noon & midday, evenning, sunset, dusk & night as synonyms. So ideally, I want something like:

```
class FuzzyTime(Enum):
        morning, dawn = 1
        noon, midday = 2
        afternoon = 3
        evening, sunset, dusk, night  = 6
```

When I use it, I want to do something like:

```
if MORNING == FuzzyTime.morning:
       pause
```

This can match both 'morning' & 'dawn'. Is that possible?

EDIT:
When I use it, I want to compare whether a string matches one of the values. Let's say my string is:

```
 s = 'morning'
 if s == FuzzyTime.morning or s == FuzzyTime.dawn:
     return get_morning_time(reference_time)
```

I just want to know whether there a way to avoid writing 'if s == or s ==' statement. I want to get rid of the 'or' in the if statement, if possible, but achieve the same effect.

Comment: Maybe `dawn = morning`?

Comment: It's possible is you simply give them the same int value, as you suggested -- but what other functionality do you need from the set of terms?  If you give them the same value, then they are equal for *all* comparisons.  Do you ever need something to match only in one direction?

Comment: @Prune Please see my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you're using enumeration values for this.  You're already having troubles to translate between a string and an enumeration label.  Just define your sets of terms:

```
class FuzzyTime():
    MORNING = {"morning", "dawn"}
    MIDDAY = {"noon", "midday"}
    AFTERNOON = {"afternoon"}
    NIGHT ={"evening", "sunset", "dusk", "night"}
```

From here, simply use the "natural" Python operator `in`

```
for s in ["dawn", "noon", "dusk"]:
    if s in FuzzyTime.MORNING:
        print("I need caffeine.")
    elif s in FuzzyTime.MIDDAY:
        print("I'm ready to solve the world's problems!")
```

... etc.

Output:

```
I need caffeine.
I'm ready to solve the world's problems!
```

Does that make it easy enough for you to use?

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'FuzzyTime' is not iterable. @Prune

Comment: It didn't work because I was a ninny: I used a single-element tuple.  AFTERNOON was a set of individual letters.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
class FuzzyTime(Enum):
    morning = dawn = 1
    noon = midday = 2
    afternoon = 3
    evening = sunset = dusk = night  = 6
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Use `in` operator:

```
class FuzzyTime:
    morning = 'morning'
    dawn = 'dawn'
    noon = 'noon'
    midday = 'midday'
    afternoon = 'afternoon'
    evening = 'evening'
    sunset = 'sunset'
    dusk = 'dusk'
    night = 'night'

    m_d = [morning, dawn]
    n_m = [noon, midday]
    e_s_d_n = [evening, sunset, dusk, night]
```

```py
s = 'morning'
if s in FuzzyTime.m_d:
    return get_morning_time(reference_time)
```

Comment: Something like that. But it doesn't help when using it. I hope a value can match both, for example, morning & dawn, but this current form has to match twice.

Comment: What do you mean? @marlon

Comment: @marlon I didn't get your point. what's the problem with my answer?

Comment: @MJafari Your answer may be good, but please take a look at my addition and to see there is something better.

Comment: s would be a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are a bit weird, but, how about a dictionary, e.g.

```
obj = {
    'morning': 1,
    'dawn': 1,
    'noon': 2,
    'midday': 2,
    'afternoon': 3,
    'evening': 6,
    'sunset': 6,
    'dusk': 6,
    'night': 6
}
```

Then, you can 'morning' with an input string, e.g.

```
str = 'dawn'
is_morning = obj[str] == obj['morning']
```